# Taking multiple pictures using camera intent. How to save those images in onActivityresult?

Tags: android, camera, onactivityresult

I am trying to take multiple photos using camera intent.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA);
```

Now The problem is I have to get All photos in onActivityResult. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to take multiple photos using camera intent Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA);

All that `Intent` action does is open up a camera app. The user does not have to take any photos, and your app does not get access to those photos that the user takes.

> Now The problem is I have to get All photos in onActivityResult

That `Intent` action does not return a result.

Either:

- Use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` to have the user take a single photo (and do this repeatedly), or
- Take the photos yourself, using the camera APIs directly or via a third-party library (e.g., Fotoapparat, CameraKit-Android)